# Table is existed but getting error SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'exyz.input_fields' doesn't exist

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, migration, laravel-seeding

i'm trying to insert values from laravel seeder. All other tables data inserted but i'm stuck on input_fields table. Even it's working on my local Mamp server absoultely fine but when i try to run on Live server getting error but as i seen the table name is existed in my database. I run "composer dumpautoload" too but still face same issue.

inputField.php

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class inputField extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'input_fields';

    public function dropDown()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\dropDown', 'drop_id');
    }
}
```

2017_10_13_093801_input_Fields

```
Schema::create('input_Fields', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('field_name');
            $table->string('cat_id');
            $table->string('description');
            $table->string('drop_id')->nullable();
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

InputFieldsTableSeeder.php

```
        $inputvalue = new inputField();
        $inputvalue->field_name = 'Bilirubin Total';
        $inputvalue->cat_id = '1';
        $inputvalue->description = '0.0 - 1.2';
        $inputvalue->save();
```

Comment: Looks like you're a bit inconsistent with the letter casing. `$table = 'input_fields'` vs `create('input_Fields', ...`. I don't know if Laravel normalizes the names to lower when you create tables, but if not, that could be an issue. Different environments/configurations can have different settings for case sensitivity for table names. Try and be consistent (change to `create('input_fields', ...`) and see if that works better.

Comment: So, did that do the trick or does the error persist?

Comment: Thank you so much. It's perfectly work for me. But can you please let me know why it's working before local but not on live server. :-).

Comment: Like I said in my first comment: _"Different environments/configurations can have different settings for case sensitivity for table names"_

Comment: I posted an answer. Feel free to accept it so others know the issue have been resolved.

Comment: thank you for quick solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're a bit inconsistent with the letter casing.

```
$table = 'input_fields'
```

and

```
create('input_Fields', ....
```

Different environments/configurations can have different settings for case sensitivity for table names. Try and be consistent and change to

```
create('input_fields', ...)
```

and it should work better.